# How to pass data from Javascript to PHP and vice versa?

Tags: php, javascript

How do I pass have a Javascript script request a PHP page and pass data to it? How do I then have the PHP script pass data back to the Javascript script?

client.js:

```
data = {tohex: 4919, sum: [1, 3, 5]};
// how would this script pass data to server.php and access the response?
```

server.php:

```
$tohex = ... ; // How would this be set to data.tohex?
$sum = ...; // How would this be set to data.sum?
// How would this be sent to client.js?
array(base_convert($tohex, 16), array_sum($sum))
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Passing data from PHP is easy, you can generate JavaScript with it. The other way is a bit harder - you have to invoke the PHP script by a Javascript request.

An example (using traditional event registration model for simplicity):

```
<!-- headers etc. omitted -->
<script>
function callPHP(params) {
    var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest(); // simplified for clarity
    var url = "get_data.php";
    httpc.open("POST", url, true); // sending as POST

    httpc.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state changes.
        if(httpc.readyState == 4 && httpc.status == 200) { // complete and no errors
            alert(httpc.responseText); // some processing here, or whatever you want to do with the response
        }
    };
    httpc.send(params);
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="callPHP('lorem=ipsum&foo=bar')">call PHP script</a>
<!-- rest of document omitted -->
```

Whatever `get_data.php` produces, that will appear in httpc.responseText. Error handling, event registration and cross-browser XMLHttpRequest compatibility are left as simple exercises to the reader ;)

See also [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) for further examples

Comment: Is worth noting that it only works with relative URLs because of the Same-origin-policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Not quite right, it work with the same domain, so absolute URLs also work. It will work cross domain if target php page have [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) enabled. Also [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is available if CORS is not an option.

Comment: This does not work. You are nowadays setting a forbidden header (content-length). What does work nowadays?

Comment: @traducerad: Pretty sure this happens automagically now and there's no need to set it, good catch.

Answer (score 13):

I run into a similar issue the other day. Say, I want to pass data from client side to server and write the data into a log file. Here is my solution:

My simple client side code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <title>Test Page</title>
   <script>
    function passVal(){
        var data = {
            fn: "filename",
            str: "this_is_a_dummy_test_string"
        };

        $.post("test.php", data);
    }
    passVal();
   </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And php code on server side:

```
<?php 
   $fn  = $_POST['fn'];
   $str = $_POST['str'];
   $file = fopen("/opt/lampp/htdocs/passVal/".$fn.".record","w");
   echo fwrite($file,$str);
   fclose($file);
?>
```

Hope this works for you and future readers!

Comment: I have following errors. Anyone knows the solution?  (index):77 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at passVal ((index):77)   -for->  $.post("test.php", data);
    at (index):79  -for->  passVal();

Comment: Found solution: Add the <script src=http://ajax.googleapis.com/ ...   line

Comment: And I found that can't receive POST content at php side. The php and javascript should be in same or different file? (I tried both. .record file is formed but no content inside it)

Answer (score 8):

I'd use [JSON](http://www.json.org) as the format and Ajax (really XMLHttpRequest) as the client->server mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

Using cookies is a easy way. You can use jquery and a pluging as [jquery.cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt) or create your own.
Using Jquery + jquery.cookie, by example

```
   <script>
   var php_value = '<?php echo $php_variable; ?>';

   var infobar_active = $.cookie('php_value');
   var infobar_alert  = any_process(infobar_active);

    //set a cookie to readit via php
   $.cookie('infobar_alerta', infobar_alerta );

   </script>

   <?php 

    var js_value = code to read a cookie

   ?>
```

I've found this usefull Server-Side and Hybrid Frameworks:
http://www.phplivex.com/
http://www.ashleyit.com/rs/

I've been using Ashley's RSJS Script to update values in HTML without any problem for a long time until I met JQuery (ajax, load, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways, the most prominent being getting form data, or getting the query string.  Here's one method using JavaScript.  When you click on a link it will call the _vals('mytarget', 'theval') which will submit the form data.  When your page posts back you can check if this form data has been set and then retrieve it from the form values.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function _vals(target, value){
   form1.all("target").value=target;
   form1.all("value").value=value;
   form1.submit();
 }
</script>
```

Alternatively you can get it via the query string.  PHP has your _GET and _SET global functions to achieve this making it much easier.

I'm sure there's probably more methods which are better, but these are just a few that spring to mind.

**EDIT:** Building on this from what others have said using the above method you would have an anchor tag like

```
<a onclick="_vals('name', 'val')" href="#">My Link</a>
```

And then in your PHP you can get form data using

```
$val = $_POST['value'];
```

So when you click on the link which uses JavaScript it will post form data and when the page posts back from this click you can then retrieve it from the PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data from PHP to javascript but the only way to get data from javascript to PHP is via AJAX.

The reason for that is you can build a valid javascript through PHP but to get data to PHP you will need to get PHP running again, and since PHP only runs to process the output, you will need a page reload or an asynchronous query.

Comment: Which isn't true, as I've just shown, I use the form submit method at work to get data from JavaScript to the server-side pretty much every day.

Comment: With a page reload or an async query?

Answer (score -2):

the other way to exchange data from php to javascript or vice versa is by using cookies, you can save cookies in php and read by your javascript, for this you don't have to use forms or ajax