# Access a javascript function value within PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Can I access the value of a javascript function from outside the function 
like if I had a function

```
<script>
function test_tree(opt)
{
    val = opt;
}
</script>
```

Can I access the `val` value from outside the `test_tree` function or is there a way to access it from PHP code?

I need to be able to access a value from the javascript code in PHP code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (including escaping newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/168214/), [How to pass a variable / data from javascript to php and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/406316/90527) and many others (depending on exactly what jarus is asking for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value to a hidden field, and read hidden field in your server side code.

```
<input type="hidden" id="myVariable">
```

In your function :

```
document.getElementById('myVariable').value = val;
```

Answer (score 4):

Considering that you didn't use `var` to declare the variable it is available to every function and all code in the global scope and beyond because without the `var` the variable is created in the global scope.

Answering your question though, if you want the variables created inside a function to exist beyond the life of a function, use a closure. You could give the variable to some object accessible outside the function which has the job of storing a bunch of these values.

If you want the variable (created in JavaScript and therefore I assume on the client) to be accessible to your PHP back end you'll have to send a request to your server. Probably an ajax call if this execution isn't part of submitting a form.