# passing javascript value inside an html page and put it in a php variable

Tags: php, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass JS variable to php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920209/how-to-pass-js-variable-to-php)
>   [pass a js variable to a php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716177/pass-a-js-variable-to-a-php-variable)

I'm passing a javascript from a script to an html page using `document.getElementById.innerHTML`. The value is printed out correctly in my html page...Now I would know it is possible take this value print in html page and (always in the same page) put it in a php variable?

Comment: 1. PHP runs on the server. Generates HTML code that is sent to the browser. 2. Javascript runs in the browser. You cannot really put something in a PHP variable that is generated in this step, because PHP has long finished running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a hidden variable like this

```
<form method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="hiddenField" id="hiddenField"/>
</form>
```

in Javascript set value for that variable

```
document.getElementById("hiddenField").value=6;
```

in PHP

```
$value=$_POST['hiddenField'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call back to a PHP script from your page, you'll have to look into [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) (or a wrapper library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Answer (score 0):

After you see a page, the php script finished, so you can only send a var via Ajax to your php file and run the script again.

one easy way to use ajax is [jquery](http://jquery.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this:

Use an XMLHttpRequest object to send an asynchronous request to some PHP page which records this value.

On the php [holdvalue.php] side:

```
<?php
    $myval = $_GET['sentval'];
    // Do something with $myval
?>
```

On the JavaScript side:

```
var x = 34; //Some interesting value
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "holdvalue.php/?sentval=" + x, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

**OR**, Use a hidden form field. On the HTML side:

```
<form id="sendform" method="get" action="holdvalue.php">
 <input type="hidden" id="sentval" />
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And on the JS side:
    document.getElementById("sentval").value = x;
    // Either the following or send it whenever the user submits the form:
    document.getElementById("sendform").submit();