# Pass variable value from JS to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I have a problem in passing a value from JS to PHP so that it can be used as a parameter for a PHP function. The JS function will be trigger by onclick event once the link was clicked. Here is the JS + HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function insertIntoDb() {
      $.GET OR POST("insert.php");
      return false;
   }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="insertIntoDb();">INSERT MY USERNAME</a>
```

PHP (insert.php):

```
<?php
    session_start();

    function insert($username){
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO List(Username) VALUES('$username')") or die(mysql_error());
    }

    if(isset($_POST['Username'])){
        insert($_POST['Username']);
    }
?>
```

Thank you for the one who can help me.. I am very new to PHP and JS so please forgive my stupidity.

Comment: Wow--wish I could add a million points for your username.  I just laughed so hard at that I might have peed myself.  Don't have an answer for ya though.  Sorry.

Comment: There's a pretty important security flaw here. You need to somehow make sure that people can't just send HTTP requests to your server, and it'll insert stuff into the database, because that can ruin your life.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt What's with my username? :)

Comment: simple CSRF reference here: http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/10/16/how-to-csrf-protect-all-your-forms/

Comment: "...passing the JS file to PHP so that it can be used as a parameter.." - are you sure?! The common way is to send a formular to the php script.

Comment: @DhaivatPandya Once they clicked the INSERT link, it will be turned into REMOVE link. so no doubling the username in the db

Comment: You change the INSERT link to a REMOVE link, and a malicious user can still bypass all that by submitting their own requests with dev tools.

Comment: think of it as this, what if the user creates his own form and points it to your PHP file. that surely bypasses the JS you have made and still runs your PHP. OR a user goes to your form, disables javascript and runs your form. same effect.

Comment: @fart-y-goer:  It's hilarious.  That's what.  I just had a good laugh again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a variable / data from javascript to php and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406316/how-to-pass-a-variable-data-from-javascript-to-php-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass data from the browser to your server.
Javascript is a language for manipulating the browser.
PHP is your server side language.

You can pass data in a get or post request such as "mypage.php?Username=john"

What you want is a form so that you can interact with the user

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function insertIntoDb() {
      document.getElementById("myform").submit();
      //or if you want to use jquery and ajax
      $.post("insert.php", $("#myform").serialize());
      return false;
    }
</script>

<form id="myform" method="post" action="insert.php">
    <a href="#" onclick="insertIntoDb();">INSERT MY USERNAME</a>
    <input type="text" name="Username"></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**index.html**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
       $("#insert").click(function(event){
           $.post('insert.php',{username:$(this).html()});
       })
   });
</script>
<a href='javascript:void(0);' id='insert'>Username</a>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
function insert($username){
    $conn = mysql_connect("host","user","passwd");
    if($conn){
        $username =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test.user(username) VALUES('".$username."')") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_close($conn);
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    insert($_POST['username']);
}
?>
```