# passing javascript value to php function

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass JS variable to php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920209/how-to-pass-js-variable-to-php)
>   [pass a js variable to a php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716177/pass-a-js-variable-to-a-php-variable)

I'm asking if it is possible passing value obtained through javascript function in a php function in the same file.for instance: I have a javascript function that calculate my position and pass this value to php function.is it possible?

[Edit]

Well I think I should be more specific...What I want to do specifically is to calculate my position through geolocation library of google API and return the value of latitude and longitude to a php variable in the way I can use it inside my php page. BUT this page it is not a normal php page it is a codeigniter Controller since I'm using MVC model to handle my project

Comment: Requires an [AJAX request](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bjavascript%5D+ajax+variable+to+php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass JS variable to php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920209/how-to-pass-js-variable-to-php) and [Pass variable value from JS to PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662976/pass-variable-value-from-js-to-php) and [pass a js variable to a php variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716177/pass-a-js-variable-to-a-php-variable) and [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pass+javascript+variable+to+php).

Comment: Can you provide more details. AJAX can do what you want, but if you will be posting a form or rerequesting the whole page then a hidden form field or cookie is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, try to look into [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp). With help from a library as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and it's ajax [methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

To call back to a server-side script from the page, you can use an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) (or a suitable wrapper such as jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

simpler way would be to create hidden form field and set its value in js and get it through php.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are two ways

- send the data directly using an ajax request, which doesn't require the whole page to be submitted
- use javascript to write the value to a hidden form element/cookie which will then get passed to your php script (either in `$_POST` or `$_COOKIE`) when you request the page again

Answer (score -1):

No, php is a server-side language as opposed to javascript, which is a client-side language.
However, you can send an AJAX response with the position variable to a PHP script (try using the jQuery post function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)