# pass value of variable x to $res

Tags: php, javascript

I am new to php and javascript...

I know js is client side n php is server side

but I want to pass value of variable x to $res

i tried using AJAX but i cant get the result..

Please help..

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

...

var x=0;
for (var i = 1; i < po; i++) {
if (Pr[i]['kRs'] == 'pSt') {
x++;
}
...

</SCRIPT>



<?php

$res=

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
if (!$con) {
   die("Database connection could not be established" . mysql_error());
}

$db_select = mysql_select_db("jaka", $con);
if (!$db_select) {
  die("Database could not be selected" . mysql_error());
}
 $bha=$_uid=$_SESSION['username'];

mysql_query("UPDATE user_info SET extra3='$res' WHERE username='$bha' ");


?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662976/pass-variable-value-from-js-to-php?rq=1

Comment: You tried AJAX, but there is no AJAX code posted here. Please post your attempt. You will need an AJAX call and your PHP looks like it is expecting `register_globals` to be enabled. The JS will post data to PHP either in `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Comment: Also, this looks like something you should be doing in PHP versus javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty example

your_page.html

```
_load_jQuery_here_

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
...
// your JavaScript code

$.ajax('saving_in_database.php?my_x=' + x);

...
</SCRIPT>
```

saving_in_database.php

```
<?php

$res = $_GET['my_x'];

// your PHP code 
?>
```

Comment: thanks for ur response i have already tried this but it show nothing in database..

Comment: You can add `print_r($res);` ,`print_r($bha);` (etc.) and run `saving_in_database.php?my_x=3` directly in browser to get as much info as you can about what PHP is doing. If PHP will work good you can add `.done()`, `.fail()` to `$.ajax` ([jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) ot see what ajax is doing.. And you can use firefox+firebug (or something similar) to see what ajax send to server and what server send back.