# how to pass javascript variables in php function

Tags: javascript, php

I have these javascript variables:

```
  $('#modalDescription').html(item.description);
  $('#exrtas-area-inside').append('<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
  <input onclick="recalculatePrice('+id+');" class="custom-control-input" id="'+element.id+'" 
  name="extra"  value="'+element.price+'" type="checkbox"><label class="custom-control-label" 
 for="'+element.id+'">'+element.name+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+'+element.priceFormated+'
  </label></div>');
```

these variables "item.description" and  "element.name"  I want to pass in php function.

Php function which is in common php file:

```
      function trsText ($text){  here language translation code }
```

now I want to pass the js parameters in that function to translate them, as I am translating php variables easily, but here name and description are coming from js code so I want to pass them in that particular php function.

Comment: If you want to send data from the browser to the server then you'd either use an AJAX request, or include them in a form post, or add them to a link or navigation event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass variable value from JS to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662976/pass-variable-value-from-js-to-php)