# Pass javascript variable to php code?

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass a variable / data from javascript to php and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406316/how-to-pass-a-variable-data-from-javascript-to-php-and-vice-versa)

I have a file of php and javascript code. I want to set a php variable to be the result of a javascript function which takes a php variable as a parameter. For example:

```
$parameter = "this is a php variable";
$phpVar = echo "foo(" . parameter . ");";
```

I know you cannot do a "= echo", is there another way I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Send using ajax, or using a form ... Depend on your case too, on what you wanna do ..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't directly do that, since JavaScript runs on the client-side and PHP gets executed on the server-side.

You would need to execute the JavaScript first and then send the result to the server via a FORM or AJAX call.

Here's what that might look like:

PHP

```
$parameter = "this is a php variable";
echo "var myval = foo(" . parameter . ");";
```

JavaScript

```
var myval = foo("this is a php variable"); // generated by PHP

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'yourphpfile.php',
  data: {'variable': myval},
});
```

Receiving PHP (yourphpfile.php)

```
$myval = $_POST['variable'];
// do something
```

Comment: The receiving PHP code is the file specified by yourphpfile.php.  It can either be separate or part of an if block in the original PHP file.

Comment: Eloquent and easy to do.

Comment: what about for multiple variables?

Answer (score 3):

PHP code is run on the server before the response is sent; JavaScript is run after, in the browser. You can't set a PHP variable from JavaScript because there are no PHP variables in the browser, where JavaScript if running. You'll have to use an AJAX request from JavaScript to a PHP script that stores whatever information it is you want to get.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, it would be more useful to explain what you find objectionable, particularly as everyone who answered after me seems to be saying the same thing I did. Is there some important nuance I got wrong? Do you just not like people named after high-quality ground meats?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var a = "Result: "+ <?php echo json_encode($parameter); ?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a `GET` or `POST` request to the script from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a js variable to php *code*.
PHP happens to run on the server, a thousand miles away from client, where js is run.

So, you can only call a php script, using js or regular hyperlink.