# How to upload file from google drive to local directory using Javascript in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, api, google-drive-api

I want  to upload file from `Google Drive` to my local folder using `Javascript`.Right now I have code in which I can download file from `Google Drive`.

But I am unable to move this file from `Google Drive` to local folder.

Can you give me suggestions to solve my problem? 
Following code gives me FileId.Now further problem I want to upload file using php.
[Sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/picker#using_the_file_picker_with_team_drives)

Comment: seems server code , not client code

Comment: It is not possible to do this in pure JavaScript. JavaScript does not have and will never have access to your local filesystem. You would need some kind of local running server or application to do this.

Comment: Thank you for suggetions. using javascript it return's me file id. now how can I solve this problem by passing file id to php code.

Comment: answer to your qeustion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623593/pass-javascript-variable-to-php-code but your question itself needs more details. Why mix javascript with php?

Comment: also...can you share the code till now please?

Comment: Now further problem I want to upload file using php. Reference code is here : 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/picker#using_the_file_picker_with_team_drives