# java script array of objects to php via ajax (jquery) and json

Tags: php, javascript, json, jquery

Here is javascript code:

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(testObj);
            $.ajax({
              url: '../php/functions/spesific_field_set.php',
              type: 'post',
              data: {fieldObjArray: jsonData, tableName: fieldTableName}
              }).always(SpesificPropertiesSet);
```

and here is the php:

```
$updates = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fieldObjArray']);
$updates = json_decode($updates, true);
$tableName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tableName']);

echo $updates;
```

What testObj is an array of object, how should I pass it to the php? and how should I access the data within this array of objects on php side?

thanks!!

Comment: `var_dump($updates)` after you `json_decode()` it to see what it looks like, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: By the way, unless you are inserting the whole JSON string directly into your database (which may be indicative of a poor design), don't call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on the input JSON from $_POST..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass data from Javascript to PHP and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406316/how-to-pass-data-from-javascript-to-php-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Learn about arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the PHP file. This should show you how you can access `$updates` that was sent through AJAX.

```
$updates = $_POST['fieldObjArray'];
$updates = json_decode($updates, true);
$tableName = $_POST['tableName'];
echo $updates; // this is an array so this would output 'Array'

foreach ($updates as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Key: '.$key.' Value: '.$value.'<br />'; // to access this, just use $updates['key']
}

// example
echo $updates['something'];
```

Comment: [www.php.net/json_decode](http://www.php.net/json_decode) --> `**assoc**: When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.` This was initially set to true in the OP's code

Comment: indeed, sorry I missed that. Still though, it is going to be a 2D array, so the 1D loop will just output `Array,Array,Array`