# How I can work with data in php which passes from javascript (jquery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I added two inputs in my html

```
<form  method="post" id="form">
    <input type="radio" name="calc-ownership" id="calc-ownership-1" value="ooo">
   <label for="calc-ownership-1" class="left-border">ООО</label>
    <input type="radio" name="calc-ownership" id="calc-ownership-2" value="ip">
    <label for="calc-ownership-2" class="right-border">ИП</label>

   <input type="radio" name="calc-activity" id="calc-activity-1" value="service">
   <label for="calc-activity-1" class="col-1">Услуги</label>

   <input type="radio" name="calc-activity" id="calc-activity-2" value="building">
   <label for="calc-activity-2" class="col-2">Строительство</label>

   <input type="radio" name="calc-activity" id="calc-activity-3" value="trade">
   <label for="calc-activity-3" class="col-1">Торговля оптовая и розничная</label>

    <input type="radio" name="calc-activity" id="calc-activity-4" value="restaurant">
   <label for="calc-activity-4" class="col-2">Ресторанный бизнес</label>

   <input type="radio" name="calc-activity" id="calc-activity-5" value="production">
   <label for="calc-activity-5" class="col-1">Производство</label>

   <input type="radio" name="calc-activity" id="calc-activity-6" value="other">
   <label for="calc-activity-6" class="col-2">Прочее</label>
```

And I added some logic with js.

```
$('.form_calc .btn_wrap .btn').click(function(){
    var path = '/intercompforme2/do.php';
    var formData = $("#form").serialize();
    var success = function( response ){
    if (response.status == "OK") {
        $('#result0').text(response.rate);
    $('#result1').text(response.sber);
    $('#result2').text(response.classic);
    $('input[name=price]').val(response.classic);
    $('input[name=price_sber]').val(response.sber);
    $('input[name=rate-name]').val(response.rate);
    if (response.rate == "ИП УСН") {
        $('.period').text('год');
        $('input[name=period]').val('год');
    }else {
        $('.period').text('месяц');
        $('input[name=period]').val('месяц');
    }
        $('.form_calc .results_wrap, .form_calc .btns_wrap').slideDown();
       }else {
           alert ("Ошибка. Обратитесь к разработчику");
       }
   }
   $.post(path, formData, success, "json");
   return false;
});
```

I want to pass this formData to my do.php.
But I don't know how to accept and work with this data.
Do PHP have global variables to accept?

I tried to just

```
$data = $_POST['calc-ownership'] ?? '';

$fp = fopen('log.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($fp, $data);
```

Then it succesfully writes to log.txt input value of calc-ownership.
But I need to pass not just one input value. I want to pass all fromData with js.

Comment: And what stops you from using other keys in `$_POST`? What is th real problem here?

Comment: I don't know other global variables to work with data arrived from js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not sure what data will be sent in a 'POST' request you can just loop through the '$_POST' array in the php file and do whatever you like with the data:

```
foreach($_POST as $field=>$data) {
    echo $field . ": " . $data . "\n";
}
```

From PHP manual, '$_POST' is:

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.

Link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But
I already have javascript  (jquery) stroke    
$.post(path, formData, success, "json");

My aim is to get json data from js.
I don't want to get data from form through PHP.
JUST accept data from js

Comment: @Cengez In that case the 'form' data can be serialized using 'serializeArray', turned into JSON and then sent in the POST request. Like so: `var formData = JSON.stringify($("#form").serializeArray());` - that way you will send a single string. Note that 'json' in '$.post' is the format in which you'd like to receive data, not send it.

Comment: ok. I edited my php:
`$data = $_POST['formData'] ?? '';`
just pass name of js variable into $_POST 
but it doesn't works

And change js:
`var formData = JSON.stringify($("#form").serializeArray());;`

Comment: Try passing the `POST` data as `{formData: formData}`.

Comment: Sorry) I can't got you

Comment: you mean like that
`var data = {
            fn: "filename",
            str: "this_is_a_dummy_test_string"
        };
`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406316/how-to-pass-data-from-javascript-to-php-and-vice-versa

Comment: I was actually using `$.ajax` instead of `$.post`. Try sending the data this way: `$.ajax({ url: path, method: "POST", data: {formData: formData} }).done(function(res) { success(res); });`

Comment: Ok but what to write in php file?

Comment: This is a way of sending your form data as JSON. With those changes `$_POST['formData']` should be populated, not empty. After that you can parse the JSON in the php file as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this name="calc-activity" on all input to maybe name="calc-activity1", name="calc-activity2" etc... and access it in your do using the php $_POST for each name

Example: in your do.php

$_POST[“calc-activity1"] 
$_POST[“calc-activity2"]

Comment: Thanks for answer. Good solution.
But this stroke of js `var formData = $("#form").serialize();`
outputs this 
`calc-ownership=ooo&calc-activity=restaurant&calc-tax=usn&calc-tax-2=charge&calc-bank=partners&calc-who-payments=client&operations_count=0&calc-nomenclature=slim&documents_count=0&calc-who-docs=client&staff_count=0&calc-more%5B%5D=patent&calc-more%5B%5D=alcohol&period=&price=&price_sber=&rate-name=&email-to=`
It means that I need to read this query then work with that